# Could not find class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper'

Tags: android, jackson

After upgrading the eclipse juno to the latest version of ADT i am having trouble with a project to compile even though it was working fine earlier.

```
Could not find class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper'
```

The full log is as follow

```
05-29 12:04:04.553: E/dalvikvm(362): Could not find class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper', referenced from method me.agilani.android.gmitthric.SplashScreenActivity.callWebService
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at me.agilani.android.gmitthric.SplashScreenActivity.callWebService(SplashScreenActivity.java:134)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at me.agilani.android.gmitthric.SplashScreenActivity.access$3(SplashScreenActivity.java:89)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at me.agilani.android.gmitthric.SplashScreenActivity$1.run(SplashScreenActivity.java:65)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-29 12:04:07.234: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have tried upgrading the jackson libraries to 2.2.1 but no avail...
can someone please help with this...

Comment: If anyone is using Android Studio and has encountered this error, I think doing ```gradle clean``` will do the trick.

Comment: Also happened to me, but with databind.MappingJsonFactory. I reordered my jackson jars, placing databind above core, then cleaned and re-built. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check your buildpath, make sure that the lib had be added to buildpath. In addtion, clean the project.

Comment: checked it, and it is there and also cleaned the project several times... no use...

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the IDE somehow, the Build path got effected. Took the external jars off the build path, Cleaned the solution multiple times and then added them again. Did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

for me org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter; and MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter got mixed up with fasterxml jackson so after gradle clean things are working now